# Access 2010 VBA JOIN expression not supported

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, inner-join

I'm attempting to write a function for Access. I have some very basic coding skills, but almost no knowledge of VBA. When I attempt to call the function from an update query, I get the "JOIN expression not supported" error, and I can't figure out what the problem is. Here's the function:

```
Function PrimaryCampus(stuPIDM As String, termCode As String) As String
Dim seqNumb As Integer
Dim seqNumbStore As Integer
Dim campus As String
Dim classCount1 As Integer
Dim classCount2 As Integer
Dim classCount3 As Integer
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
seqNumb = 0
classCount1 = 0
classCount2 = 0
classCount3 = 1
Set db = CurrentDb
Do While (seqNumb < 7)
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB) " & _
                               "FROM SATURN_SFRSTCR " & _
                               "INNER JOIN SATURN_SSBSECT " & _
                                  "ON SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT_TERM_CODE " & _
                                  "AND SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT_CRN " & _
                               "WHERE SFRSTCR_PIDM = '" & stuPIDM & "' " & _
                                 "AND SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '" & termCode & "' " & _
                                 "AND SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB LIKE '" & seqNumb & "*';")
    classCount1 = rec.Fields(0)
    If (classCount2 < classCount1) Then
        classCount2 = classCount1
        seqNumbStore = seqNumb
    ElseIf (classCount2 = classCount1) Then
        classCount3 = classCount3 + 1
    End If
    seqNumb = seqNumb + 1
Loop
If (classCount3 > 1) Then
    campus = CStr(classCount3)
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 0) Then
    campus = "Distance Learning"
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 1) Then
    campus = "Clarkston"
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 2) Then
    campus = "Dunwoody"
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 3) Then
    campus = "Decatur"
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 5) Then
    campus = "Newton"
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 6) Then
    campus = "Alpharetta"
End If
PrimaryCampus = campus
rec.Close
Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

I'm sure there are other errors because I'm using code I don't fully understand, but I need to fix the select statement before I can continue with the debugging. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Thanks to everyone who helped me out. Here's the working version of the code for anyone who, like me, is a complete novice to VBA functions:

```
Function PrimaryCampus(stuPIDM As Long, termCode As String) As String
Dim seqNumb As Integer
Dim seqNumbStore As Integer
Dim campus As String
Dim classCount1 As Integer
Dim classCount2 As Integer
Dim classCount3 As Integer
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
seqNumb = 0
classCount1 = 0
classCount2 = 0
classCount3 = 1 
Set db = CurrentDb
Do While (seqNumb < 7)
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB) AS CAMP_COUNT " & _
                               "FROM SATURN_SFRSTCR " & _
                               "INNER JOIN SATURN_SSBSECT " & _
                                 "ON SATURN_SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SATURN_SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE " & _
                                 "AND SATURN_SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SATURN_SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN " & _
                               "WHERE SFRSTCR_PIDM = " & stuPIDM & " " & _
                                 "AND SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '" & termCode & "' " & _
                                 "AND SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB LIKE '" & seqNumb & "*' " & _
                                 "AND (SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'R*' OR SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'W*') " & _
                                 "AND SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR >= 1")
    classCount1 = rec.Fields(0)
    If (classCount1 = 0) Then
        classCount1 = 0
    ElseIf (classCount2 < classCount1) Then
        classCount2 = classCount1
        seqNumbStore = seqNumb
    ElseIf (classCount2 = classCount1) Then
        classCount3 = classCount3 + 1
    End If
    seqNumb = seqNumb + 1
Loop
If (classCount3 > 1) Then
    campus = CStr(classCount3)
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 0) Then
    campus = "Distance Learning"
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 1) Then
    campus = "Clarkston"
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 2) Then
    campus = "Dunwoody"
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 3) Then
    campus = "Decatur"
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 5) Then
    campus = "Newton"
ElseIf (seqNumbStore = 6) Then
    campus = "Alpharetta"
End If
PrimaryCampus = campus
rec.Close
Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Bugs I had to fix:

1. Explicit table names in the join criteria.
2. stuPidm is a NUMBER(8) field. Originally, stuPIDM was an Integer,
   but this was causing a type conversion failure when I ran my update
   query. I didn't realize Integer in Access VBA was equivalent to a
   short integer in other languages, so the type needed to be Long.
3. I also needed to fix a logic error in the loop's If statement where
   I wasn't dealing with counts of 0.

Comment: you might try and use the table names in the `ON` clause  e.g. ` SATURN_SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SATURN_SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE ...` I would also alias your count column. That said its probably a good idea to print your SQL and throw it in a Query, which will make it much easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Adding the table names seems to have fixed the join error, but now I have a "Datatype mismatch in criteria expression error." At least that's one bug down.

Comment: @anbisme - Remember that **text** fields have to be surrounded by single quotes, and **integer** fields do not.  "Datatype Mismatch" errors are usually due to the user trying to set one equal to the other.  Make sure your SEQ_NUMB field is actually text, because it sounds like it should be an integer (which would mean you need to remove the single quotes surrounding it).

Comment: The error was caused by stuPIDM, which is a number in the table, so I changed its type to Integer which got rid of the error. But now, when I run my update query, I get a "type conversion failure" for all the records. I don't understand why because, as far as I can tell, I'm returning a String to a text field. Also strange is that Access doesn't seem to care if I put single quotes around stuPIDM or not. Edit: Apparently not so strange. Oracle doesn't seem to care about the single quotes either. I've just always used them for that particular field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly referencing the table and field in the join like so:

```
"SELECT COUNT(SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB) " & _
"FROM SATURN_SFRSTCR " & _
"INNER JOIN SATURN_SSBSECT " & _
"ON SATURN_SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SATURN_SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE " & _
"AND SATURN_SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SATURN_SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN " & _
"WHERE SFRSTCR_PIDM = '" & stuPIDM & "' " & _
"AND SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '" & termCode & "' " & _
"AND SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB LIKE '" & seqNumb & "*';"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, so I'm checking it for anyone who comes across this question. But, credit where credit is due, it was given first by @Conrad Frix in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966%28v=office.15%29.aspx), it seems like you will have to specify a recordset type or it will assume you're trying to call a table rather than a query. Try:

```
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB) " & _
                             "FROM SATURN_SFRSTCR " & _
                             "INNER JOIN SATURN_SSBSECT " & _
                                "ON SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT_TERM_CODE " & _
                                "AND SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT_CRN " & _
                             "WHERE SFRSTCR_PIDM = '" & stuPIDM & "' " & _
                               "AND SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '" & termCode & "' " & _
                               "AND SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB LIKE '" & seqNumb & "*';", _
                             Type:=dbOpenDynamic)
```

Comment: I get an invalid argument error. It will accept dbOpenSnapshot from the example on the page you linked to, but then it just brings me back to the JOIN expression not supported error.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I remember, Access doesn't allow two pairs of fields in a JOIN, so you need to move the second one to the WHERE clause:

```
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB) " & _
                           "FROM SATURN_SFRSTCR " & _
                           "INNER JOIN SATURN_SSBSECT " & _
                              "ON SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT_TERM_CODE " & _
                           "WHERE SFRSTCR_PIDM = '" & stuPIDM & "' " & _
                             "AND SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '" & termCode & "' " & _
                             "AND SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB LIKE '" & seqNumb & "*'" & _
                              "AND SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT_CRN " & ";")
```

In the above the clause `"AND SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT_CRN "` has been moved from the JOIN to the WHERE.

Comment: I tried it but the error remains. Access will let me build an equivalent query in design view where it places parentheses around each of the join conditions. I've tried that also with no luck.